# Linecolor not changing after including png binary

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I would like to include the `png`-file [boompje.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgNyi.png) in my Gnuplot graph, which I do using the following line of code:

```
plot 'boompje.png' binary filetype=png origin=(120,-10) dx=0.008 dy=0.008 with rgbimage
```

The problem is that after I do this, the color of the `y=0`-line changes to black ([see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0klJ.png)) although I have declared it to be `dark-plume`. This is my Gnuplotscript:

```
set term pngcairo size 1080,720
set output 'schuine_worp.png'
set size ratio -1
set xrange[0:250]
set yrange[-10:100]
set xlabel 'x (m)'
set ylabel 'y (m)'
set title 'schuine worp'
unset key

plot 'boompje.png' binary filetype=png origin=(120,-10) dx=0.008 dy=0.008 with rgbimage,\
'schuine_worp.dat' u 4:5 w p pt 7 ps 0.8,\ 
0 linecolor 'dark-plume' with filledcurves x1
```

For the sake of completeness, the file `schuine_worp.dat`:

```
time    x0  y0  x1  y1  energy error    step size
1e-05   121.1   -6370000    0.000290000000009342    0.000409999508613916    0   1e-05
0.200010000000059   121.1   -6370000    5.80029367739884    8.00383607717226    0   1e-05
0.400010000000259   121.1   -6370000    11.6003044702085    15.6141542714974    0   1e-05
0.600009999999904   121.1   -6370000    17.400322020473 22.8313655217641    1.81604519864699e-16    1e-05
0.800009999998994   121.1   -6370000    23.200345970239 29.6554707187308    1.81604519864699e-16    1e-05
1.00000999999808    121.1   -6370000    29.0003759615572    36.0864707046356    0   1e-05
1.20000999999939    121.1   -6370000    34.8004116364803    42.1243662731976    0   1e-05
1.4000100000007 121.1   -6370000    40.6004526370649    47.7691581696169    0   1e-05
1.60001000000201    121.1   -6370000    46.400498605369 53.0208470905712    0   1e-05
1.80001000000332    121.1   -6370000    52.2005491834544    57.879433684223 0   1e-05
2.00001000000464    121.1   -6370000    58.0006040133843    62.3449185502169    0   1e-05
2.20001000000595    121.1   -6370000    63.8006627372232    66.4173022396778    0   1e-05
2.40001000000726    121.1   -6370000    69.6007249970406    70.0965852552175    0   1e-05
2.60001000000857    121.1   -6370000    75.4007904349027    73.3827680509233    0   1e-05
2.80001000000988    121.1   -6370000    81.2008586928824    76.2758510323731    1.81604519864699e-16    1e-05
3.00001000001119    121.1   -6370000    87.0009294130507    78.7758345566268    0   1e-05
3.2000100000125 121.1   -6370000    92.8010022374819    80.8827189322266    1.81604519864699e-16    1e-05
3.40001000001381    121.1   -6370000    98.6010768082489    82.5965044192003    0   1e-05
3.60001000001512    121.1   -6370000    104.401152767427    83.91719122906  0   1e-05
3.80001000001643    121.1   -6370000    110.201229757093    84.8447795248006    0   1e-05
4.00001000001774    121.1   -6370000    116.001307419323    85.3792694209038    0   1e-05
4.20001000001017    121.1   -6370000    121.80138539619 85.5206609833359    0   1e-05
4.40001000000259    121.1   -6370000    127.60146332978 85.2689542295455    0   1e-05
4.60000999999502    121.1   -6370000    133.401540862163    84.6241491284684    0   1e-05
4.80000999998745    121.1   -6370000    139.201617635417    83.5862456005241    0   1e-05
5.00000999997988    121.1   -6370000    145.001693291617    82.1552435176159    0   1e-05
5.20000999997231    121.1   -6370000    150.801767472841    80.3311427031338    0   1e-05
5.40000999996474    121.1   -6370000    156.601839821162    78.113942931951 0   1e-05
5.60000999995716    121.1   -6370000    162.401909978656    75.5036439304269    0   1e-05
5.80000999994959    121.1   -6370000    168.201977587395    72.5002453764   0   1e-05
6.00000999994202    121.1   -6370000    174.00204228945 69.1037468991974    0   1e-05
6.20000999993445    121.1   -6370000    179.802103726892    65.3141480796298    0   1e-05
6.40000999992688    121.1   -6370000    185.60216154179 61.1314484499869    0   1e-05
6.60000999991931    121.1   -6370000    191.402215376209    56.5556474940451    0   1e-05
6.80000999991173    121.1   -6370000    197.202264872216    51.5867446470647    0   1e-05
7.00000999990416    121.1   -6370000    203.002309671869    46.2247392957841    0   1e-05
7.20000999989659    121.1   -6370000    208.802349417236    40.4696307784281    0   1e-05
7.40000999988902    121.1   -6370000    214.602383750372    34.3214183846989    1.81604519864699e-16    1e-05
7.60000999988145    121.1   -6370000    220.402412313331    27.780101355783 0   1e-05
7.80000999987388    121.1   -6370000    226.202434748166    20.8456788843452    0   1e-05
8.00000999986631    121.1   -6370000    232.002450696924    13.518150114531 0   1e-05
8.20000999985873    121.1   -6370000    237.802459801655    5.79751414196492    0   1e-05
8.40000999985116    121.1   -6370000    243.602461704401    -2.31622998624952   0   1e-05
8.60000999984359    121.1   -6370000    249.402456047201    -10.8230832715312   0   1e-05
8.80000999983602    121.1   -6370000    255.20244247209 -19.7230467638209   0   1e-05
9.00000999982845    121.1   -6370000    261.0024206211  -29.0161215615829   0   1e-05
9.20000999982088    121.1   -6370000    266.802390136256    -38.7023088118069   0   1e-05
9.4000099998133 121.1   -6370000    272.602350659585    -48.7816097100059   0   1e-05
9.60000999980573    121.1   -6370000    278.402301833104    -59.2540255002175   0   1e-05
9.80000999979816    121.1   -6370000    284.202243298828    -70.1195574750095   1.81604519864699e-16    1e-05
10.0000099997906    121.1   -6370000    290.002174698766    -81.3782069754736   1.81604519864699e-16    1e-05
```

Comment: What if you use `set terminal png truecolor`, or `set terminal pngcairo`?